# uploading multiple images on ajax cross domain

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am uploading multiple images cross domain using Ajax and php.
I have set the loader before the Ajax call
Everything works good but when i select multiple images to upload the loader comes after big time delay.

Below is my code

```
 $('#load-div').css('display', 'block'); 
    var data = new FormData();
    var c = 0;
    var files = new Array(); 

    $.each($('#file')[c].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('files'+i, file);
        c++;
    });

    var other_data = $('#frmaddproperty').serializeArray();
    $.each(other_data, function(key, input){
        data.append(input.name, input.value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Coss domain url',
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false,  

cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data:data,

            success: function(response){


            console.log(response);
            window.location = 'property_list.php?msg='+response;


            },
            error: function(){                      
                //alert('Error while request..');
            },
        });
```

Above is my code i have set loader in Div id load-div.
it comes after very big delay of time when i upload multiple images.
Don't know what to do about it.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have more code to show? It seems like you cut half of it off. Also note that you can provide a `form` DOMElement to `FormData` so you don't need to loop through and populate it manually.

Comment: below is my Ajax request. it works well. but problem with loader which i put just before ajax call

Comment: its difficult to guess the problem like this, can you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net . for making ajax calls on jsfiddle, you can always mock them

Answer (score 0):

You can use "ajaxStart()".
https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

It will start the loader when your call starts.

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $('#load-div').css('display', 'block'); 
});
```

**UPDATE**

You can also use, "beforeSend".

```
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    beforeSend: function() {
    $('#load-div').css('display', 'block');
},
```

Read more about your options:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**UPDATE**

I guess it's this loop that is making the delay.
Try putting the loader inside of it.
Or else you need to give us more code, to figure out what's making the delay!

```
$.each($('#file')[c].files, function(i, file) {
  $('#load-div').css('display', 'block'); 
  data.append('files'+i, file);
  c++;
});
```

Comment: loader display properly but takes time delay when multiple image upload.
i tried your code but same problem comes

Comment: Also with: beforeSend?

Comment: same problem with beforeSend

Answer (score 0):

```
async: false,
```

I have removed this line from my ajax call and loader is working fine. 
what it is stands for i don't know

Comment: Any one know about async:false, what does it realy do?